# How to access camera on Instagram app browser?

Tags: ios, iphone, instagram

When I open [this page](https://demo.kasperkamperman.com/mobilecamtemplate/) on Safari on iPhone, it can access camera. If I put this link to Instagram and open the link, it will open the page on in-app web browser on Instagram, but camera is not working. Is there any way to make it?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do with the camera and resulting image or video, you can use an input:

```
<input type="file" />
```

This causes iOS to open the choose file dialogue which includes the option to "Take Photo or Video":

[image: Upload file dialogue]

While you don't have direct access to the camera feed you can get the resulting image or video as an output which for some situations might be enough.